# Is it possible to detect free spaces in a document to place images?

Tags: graphics

We generate PDFs with dynamic content. Moreover we would like to place some additional images or advertisements at blank spots in the document.

For example we have a page with a title and a description on the first page. 40% of the page is blank, so we would like to place an image there to fill the page.

Is there a way to get this behaviour?

Comment: What causes the blank spaces?

Comment: The defined constraints and the height of our text blocks. Sometimes it has to make a page break for the next topic and then we got a possible blank spot.

Comment: Does the page break involve something like clearpage?

Comment: hello, as I said on github it depends a lot on the details of the space, it is for example easier to test that `\vspace{\fill}` has been stretched from its default of 0pt to (say) 5cm to fill the page than if there is a `\vspace{5cm}` on the page that will look like the same 5cm of vertical space but is (in some cases) harder to detect that it is white space as it has a fixed size, like a box.  So a small complete example document would be useful.

Comment: also as samcarter hinted, if the page breaks to be considered are always at a sectioning command (for example) it may be easier to define that command to insert the adverts when there is space rather than catching short pages later after the pages are made up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This partial solution uses the `notespages` package and its command `\notesfill` to insert things on the remaining space of a page. Here a new notes style `graphic` is defined, which is meant to insert a picture. The new option `graphic` is used to pass the commands to insert a picture to the notes style. An example for this is shown in section 4. The default is to print the remaining height.

Where ever `\notesfill` appears in the source, it fills the remainder of the current page. So it makes sense to put it before any appearance of `\newpage`, `\clearpage` or commands calling them (e.g. `\chapter` or `\include`). It has to be in its own paragraph.

The material inserted by `\notesfill` will be moved to the bottom of the page, if it uses less then the remaining height. If this is unwanted, you have to add the option `filltopfill=false`.

The option `fillminspace` sets the minimum height to insert something. An example can be seen on page 3, where the space left is less then the given `0.25\textheight`. Although there is a `\notesfill` in the source, nothing is inserted here.

The main file (fill-empty-space-with-pictures.tex):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{notespages}
\usepackage{currfile}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\makeatletter
% write information about free space to \jobname.gsh (gsh: graphic space height)
\AtEndDocument{\if@filesw\newwrite\tf@gsh
  \immediate\openout\tf@gsh\jobname.gsh\fi
}
\newcommand{\np@graphic@writeinfo}{%
    \protected@write\@auxout{}%
      {\string\@writefile{gsh}{\the\inputlineno; \the\c@page; \the\graphicheight; \currfilename}}%
}

% necessary because of rounding error, presumably by the graphicx package
\newdimen\graphicheight
\newcommand{\np@calc@graphicheight}{%
    \graphicheight\remainingtextheight
    \advance\graphicheight-0.1\p@
}

% default for option graphic
\newcommand{\np@graphic@default}{%
    \centering remaining height: \the\graphicheight
}

% the new graphic option
\newcommand{\np@graphic}{}
\key@ifundefined{np}{graphic}{}{\np@err@defined{graphic}}
\define@key{np}{graphic}[\np@graphic@default]{\def\np@graphic{%
    \np@calc@graphicheight\np@graphic@writeinfo #1\par}}

% initialize it
\setkeys{np}{graphic}

% new notes style
\definenotesstyle{graphic}{\np@graphic}

\makeatother

% global settings
\setnotespages{
    filltopskip=2ex,
    fillminspace=0.25\textheight,
    notesstyle=graphic
}

% for advertisments
\definenotesoption{advert}{%
    titlestyle=text,
    titletext={\centering Advertisement},
    titleskip=1ex
}

% for other graphics
\definenotesoption{normal}{%
    titlestyle=none
}

\begin{document}
\section{Section One}
\lipsum[1-3]

\notesfill[advert]

\newpage
\section{Section Two}
\lipsum[1-2]

\notesfill[advert]

\newpage
\section{Section Three}
\lipsum[1-4]

\notesfill[advert]

\newpage
\input{fill-empty-space-with-pictures_a}
\end{document}
```

The included file (fill-empty-space-with-pictures_a.tex):

```
\section{Section Four}
\lipsum[1]

\notesfill[advert,graphic={\centering\includegraphics[height=\graphicheight,width=\textwidth,keepaspectratio]{example-image.pdf}}]

\newpage
\section{Section Five}
\lipsum[2]

\notesfill[normal]

\newpage
\section{Section Six}
\lipsum[4]

\notesfill[advert]
```

The new notes style also writes information about the free space into a file `\jobname.gsh`. It's in csv format (`;` as column delimiter) and contains four columns: the line number of the `\notesfill` command in the source, the page number, the remaining height for a picture and the file name of the source (to get the file name for included files, the `currfile` package is used). Note that there is no entry for page 3, because there wasn't enough space for a picture. Here is an example:

```
66; 1; 204.08061pt; fill-empty-space-with-pictures.tex
72; 2; 324.08061pt; fill-empty-space-with-pictures.tex
4; 4; 408.08061pt; fill-empty-space-with-pictures_a.tex
10; 5; 482.44171pt; fill-empty-space-with-pictures_a.tex
16; 6; 468.08061pt; fill-empty-space-with-pictures_a.tex
```

There is some work left for you: write a script, which reads the `.gsh` file, selects pictures with the right height, adds the option `graphic={...}` with the appropriate commands to insert the picture to `\notesfill` in the source and finally recompile it.

Please note that, depending on if there is a title above the picture ('Advertisement' in the example) or not, the remaining height will differ (see pages 5 and 6). So if you want to change that in your script, you have to correct the height. While a picture with a height less then the remaining won't cause a problem, a picture too high will mess up things.

[image]